# How to access (read/write) sd card public directory? Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory return internal storage

Tags: android, android-sdcard

How to access (read/write) sd card public directory?

Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory return internal storage paths.
getExternalFilesDirs return both internal storage and sd card. But app specific paths.
What about public shared directories on sd card? And attached usb drive? How to get access to them?

Comment: "Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory return internal storage paths" -- no, it returns paths for what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). Also note that this method is deprecated. "What about public shared directories on sd card? And attached usb drive? How to get access to them?" -- use the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`).

Comment: It's a question of simantics. "Internal storage" or "what the Android SDK refers to as external storage". It exactly not sd card. Or usb attached drive. Where to find guide how to use "Storage Access Framework"?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files

Comment: There is nothing about how to access sd card or usb attached drive.

Comment: Those will appear in the Storage Access Framework UI as available storage locations automatically. Your code neither knows nor cares whether the user chooses on-board flash, removable devices, Google Drive, or any other `DocumentsProvider` implementation.

Comment: The user cannot touch into the User Interface(even Storage Access Framework) every time the application automatically writes a file.

Comment: Then use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to request access to an entire directory (or other form of document tree). You can then create whatever you need in there. If you take persistable `Uri` permissions, you can create whatever you need in there over time.

Comment: startActivityForResult is deprecated already. And all https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files as well. New method - registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree()) need for launch Uri! parametr. Where it get from? https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files talks Uri is optional. But in launch(Uri!) is not null. I am stuck.

Comment: Okey. I used depricated startActivityForResult. Got Uri. Call method contentResolver.query(Uri, null,null,null... and got  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Uri content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/1B07-1103%3APictures... Storage Access Framework returns unusable Uris?

Comment: It will depend a lot on what you are trying to do with the `Uri`. Usually, `DocumentFile` as a wrapper will suffice. See [this blog post series](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/19/scoped-storage-stories-saf-basics.html) for more about using the Storage Access Framework (and `MediaStore`, for that matter).

Comment: I try read and write directories on sd card. And on usb flash drive, when attach it to smartphone. Public directory. Pictures. Downloads. It is on initial question: How to access (read/write) sd card public directory?

Comment: I use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to get access to to dirrectory. Got content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADownload. Then call contentResolver.query(Uri, null,null,null.. to get cursor for all files in directory.  Uri = content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADownload . it caused me error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Uri content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADownload.  What is wrong?

Comment: query
Added in API level 1
Cursor query (Uri uri, 
Uri: The URI, using the content:// scheme, for the content to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of obsoleted java File framework I found another deprecated startActivityForResult function. There is not obsolete, but still beta registerForActiviResult. But I cannot found what Uri to pass to launch of this. Because of this I've compelled to use  startActivityForResult to get Uri to Direcroty:

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).apply {
        flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
}
startActivityForResult(intent,10)
```

Then from gotten Uri from deprecated onActivityResult make another Uri because first one not suitable to check freespace on a drive.

```kotlin
val docUriTree = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(u,DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(u))
val fd = app.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(docUriTree,"r")
val st = Os.fstatvfs(fd?.fileDescriptor)
Log.d(TAG, "sUr: Free ${st.f_bsize * st.f_bavail / 1024 / 1024} MByes  f_bsize: ${st.f_bsize} Bytes  f_bavail: ${st.f_bavail}")
```

Then list of files...

```kotlin
val df = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(app.applicationContext, u)
val dfl = df?.listFiles()
dfl?.forEach {
       Log.d("MY_TAG",
"\n-------------------\n$it\nname: ${it.name}\nparentFile: ${it.parentFile}\nuri: ${it.uri}\ntype: ${it.type}\nlength: ${it.length()}\nlastModified: ${it.lastModified()}\n-------------------------\n"
       )
       // Do something with it like:
      filelist.add(
                ImageFile(
                    fUri = it.uri,
                    Name = it.name,
                    bitmap = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                        DocumentsContract.getDocumentThumbnail(
                            app.contentResolver, it.uri,
                            Point(190, 108), null
                        )
                    else
                        null
                )
            )
}
```

What I cannot figure out is how to use beta registerForActivityResult instead of deprecated startActivityForResult.

p.s.

Finally found what to pass to launch. It is DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI.

```kotlin
registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree()) {
          if (it != null) {
                   viewModel.sUr(it)
          }
}.launch(Uri.parse(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI))
```

What another parameters can be passed to launch?
What is DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI means?

Comment: more code: https://github.com/s3va/Test_Work. There is recyclerview of pictures of selected directory.